# Error: parsing d="MNaN,260L on D3.js multiline graph with JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I'm trying to show at least one line of a graph with this, hopefully to be adding a second later. I just can't get anything to show up though, when this hits the line `return line(d.values);` I get `Error: parsing d="MNaN,260L...` for a bunch of lines. I started out with [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955), my data structure is identical to the one in that example, and I kept all the variable names and when I console.log(cities), my structure is the same. Ideas?

`cities` var looks like :

```
[
    {name:"count", values: [{date:1, temperature: 10}, {date:1, temperature: 10}]}
]
```

JS code looks like:

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 0, bottom: 20, left: 20},
                    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
                    height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

                var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y%m%d").parse;

                var x = d3.time.scale()
                    .range([0, width]);

                var y = d3.scale.linear()
                    .range([height, 0]);

                var color = d3.scale.category10();

                var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                    .scale(x)
                    .orient("bottom");

                var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                    .scale(y)
                    .orient("left");

                var line = d3.svg.line()
                    .interpolate("basis")
                    .x(function(d) {
                        console.log(d)
                        return x(d.date); 
                    })
                    .y(function(d) { 
                        return y(d.temperature); 
                    });

                var svg = d3.select(".heartbeat").append("svg")
                    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                  .append("g")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


                d3.json("/static/data/test.json", function(error, data) {
                  color.domain(["one"]);

                    function get_vs(){
                        a = []
                        $.each(data, function(k, v){
                            if(v.hasOwnProperty("CN")){
                                a.push({"date": new Date(), "temperature": v.CN.count})
                            }else{
                                a.push({"date": new Date(), "temperature": 0})
                            }
                        })
                        return a
                    }

                    var cities = [
                        {
                            name: "count",
                            values: get_vs()
                        }
                    ]

                  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));

                  y.domain([
                    d3.min(cities, function(c) { return d3.min(c.values, function(v) { return v.temperature; }); }),
                    d3.max(cities, function(c) { return d3.max(c.values, function(v) { return v.temperature; }); })
                  ]);

                  svg.append("g")
                      .attr("class", "x axis")
                      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                      .call(xAxis);

                  svg.append("g")
                      .attr("class", "y axis")
                      .call(yAxis)

                  var city = svg.selectAll(".city")
                      .data(cities)
                    .enter().append("g")
                      .attr("class", "city");

                  city.append("path")
                      .attr("class", "line")
                      .attr("d", function(d) { 
                        return line(d.values); 
                        })
                      .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.name); });
                });
```

Comment: It looks like all your dates are the same, so the extent of the x scale would be 0.

Comment: You're right - but would that cause a parsing error? Going to try it out just to be sure...

Comment: Well the scale would return NaN. What the scale returns is part of the path string and a NaN in that is illegal.

Comment: nope, same problem. I had tried earlier with timestamps, not much luck either. I think the issue is elsewhere.

Comment: Hmm, not sure what you're trying to do, but it looks like your `.values` is always empty, i.e. array of length 0.

Comment: Just got it to work with a lot of duct taping - my data format was off. I'll update here after I've cleaned this up a little :) thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data just needed a bit of adapting - the original code was expecting an array of objects.

```
data = []
d3.json("/static/data/test.json", function(error, json_data) {
    $.each(json_data, function(k, v){                            
        a = {count: count, avg: avg, date: date}
        data.push(a)
    })
 })
```